# Weighted Averages For Grades. But, no score for the final yet. How can I calc?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics, standard-deviation

10% for Participation
10% for Workbooks
10% for Quizzes
40% for Tests
30% for Final Test.

Students are asking for their current grade but I thought since one column is blank (final test, not taken) I could not calc it out. Instead of 100% it is 70% and the numbers are abit strange. Can someone help me calc a current grade without a input for Final Test?

Thanks

Comment: I am a teacher, and I often have the kind of problem you address here. @Alan's answer is correct and how I calculated grades in my spreadsheet (until we were told to use a standardized computer application which clearly does the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

To get their current grade,  just add up the weighted results of each of the things currently recorded, then divide by the total weight.  So,  here assigning the variables P for participation, W for workbook, Q for quiz, and T for test, the current average would be $\frac {.1P+.1W+.1Q+.4T} {.7}$